# Cakephp Set::combine keep numeric keys

Tags: cakephp, set

I want to get an numeric array out of Set::combine in cakePhp.

```
Set::combine($results, '{n}', '{n}.Tag.name')
```

But this doesn't work as I expected because '{n}' is Array and not the index, like I thought. This doesn't work neither

```
Set::combine($results, '', '{n}.Tag.name') 
//OR
Set::combine($results, '{n}.Tag.name')
```

In the documentation http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html I didn't find anything that helped me.

Is it possible to use Set::combine to get an array in the same numeric order like it is passed into the function keeping the numeric keys or do I have to transform the keys in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the function Set::classicExtract that works!

```
 Set::classicExtract($results, '{n}.Tag.name')
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Combine]

You are using a method `combine` but only specify one thing...

If you want just the names use `Set::extract($results, '{n}.Tag.name')` or for 2.x `Hash::extract($results, '{n}.Tag.name')`

This will give `array(0 => name, 1 => name)`. The order is never affected.